# php merge queries left join and if else statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query to fetch information about *productID, numOfLikes, isLiked.*

The thing is I can't figure how to merge first query with the second.

1. first query runs on an array of numbers and returns the *productID, numOfLikes* of the products from the database.

   ```
   $result = $connection->query("SELECT productID, numOfLikes 
                                 FROM Products 
                                 WHERE productID IN (".implode(", ", array_map('intval', $arr)));
   ```
2. second query check a match of both *productID* and *customerID* to be present on a same line in a *CustomerProduct*s table.

   ```
   "SELECT customerID, productID 
   FROM CustomerProducts 
   WHERE productID = ".$productID." AND customerID = ".$customerID;
   ```

And I would like to know how to make the second query return true if finds a match.

I added a Database Schema, if that might help.

[image: DB Schema]

EDIT:
Data that is sent to the php page looks like this:
{ **customerId**: **107678695429**, gArrayOfProductIds: [ {productId: 52979957765}, {productId: 69128650757}, {productId: 69757075461},{productId: 69833654277} ] }

**Example:**

First query:
[image]

CustomerProducts table with productIds provided from the data:
[image]

Query after Merge:
[image]

As you can see customerId: 107678695429 liked 3 products, but didn't like the 4th and a product can be liked by many people.

**HUGE thanks for people who might help.**

**ANSWER:**

I combined the answers of **rolfv1** and **Susang**.

Query:

```
SELECT p.productID, p.numOfLikes, CASE WHEN cp.customerID IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END isLiked FROM Products p LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.productID = p.productID AND cp.customerID = 107678695429 WHERE p.productID IN (52979957765,69833654277,69757075461,69128650757)
```

PHP Query:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT p.productID, p.numOfLikes,CASE WHEN cp.customerID IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END isLiked FROM Products p LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.productID = p.productID AND cp.customerID = ".$customerID." WHERE p.productID IN (".implode(", ", array_map('intval', $arr)).")");
```

**HUGE THANKS TO rolfv1 and Susang**.

Comment: Schema just shows what you have but what you want is shown by sample data and desired output so please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `productID` is the same across both tables, you could use this query:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT p.productID, p.numOfLikes, cp.customerID FROM Products p LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.productID = p.productID WHERE p.productID IN (".implode(", ", array_map('intval', $arr)).")");
```

EDIT:
And to show true/false if a customer is found or not, use something like

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT p.productID, p.numOfLikes, cp.customerID, CASE WHEN cp.customerID IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END customerFound FROM Products p LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.productID = p.productID WHERE p.productID IN (".implode(", ", array_map('intval', $arr)).")");
```

(Also note the parenthesis added at the end of the query to close the `IN ()`.)

(And note that I assumed you sanitize the input variables for your query before using them)

Comment: Hey rolfv1 thanks for the help. But how would i make it show true or false if found a match of customerId and productId in CustomerProducts?the point is not to output customerId but a true or false in the third select column.

Comment: THANKS for the answer rolfv1. I combined you answer with Susang's and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** If I am right with your requirement then you can achieve your desired output with `LEFT JOIN` and `CASE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN cp.productID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS TrueFalse 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN CustomerProducts cp ON cp.productID = p.productID
    AND cp.productID = 5 AND cp.customerID = 6
```

Comment: THANKS for the answer Susang. I combined you answer with rolfv1's and it solved my problem.